# Let Node.js and PHP use the same database(mysql)?

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

I built a application using PHP, and I want to make my application have a real-time service. So, I use socket.io with Node.js. But, how to let Node.js and PHP use the same database(mysql)?

Comment: Try connecting to the same database from PHP and node.js and see what happens!

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you need to do anything special. The database is a separate entity so just connect to it normally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

install mysql module for nodejs.

```
npm install mysql
```

using his module you can use the mysql database

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var conn = mysql.createConnection(
    {
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : '.....',
      password : '......',
       database : '.......'
    }
);
conn.connect();

var queryString = 'SELECT * FROM .............';
conn.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) { 
                 console.log(err);
            } else {
                        console.log(rows);
                    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I figure out my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

[There's a module](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-db-mysql) for nodejs that allows you to connect to MySQL. It is pretty easy to use:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');

var conn = mysql.createConnection({
     host     : 'localhost',
     user     : 'root',
     password : ''
});

conn.connect(function(err) {});
```